# Convert .NET Forms App to .NET 5, why are some forms no longer recognized

Tags: vb.net, .net-5

When I converted the vbproj file and started VS I noticed that several of my forms are no longer recognized as forms. What happened, is it fixable?

Comment: If you used the project upgrade CLI tools, they are useless when it comes to ‘linked’ files - they will not handle the corresponding ‘Dependent’ files properly or omit them entirely.